# How to know how many restrictions are there?

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

In chi-squared test 'new' is equal to number of independent variables- no. of restrictions

In one of the examples in the book, 100 numbers are generated between 0 and 9.To check whether these numbers are random a chi squared test is performed with a 5% significance level.The book says that 'new'=10-1=9.Frequency here is the restriction.

nut in another example where 5 coins are tossed 192 times and no. of head throws are summarized in atable (example - 0 heads-7 times,1 heads-25 times,etc..).Here 'new' is 5.

My question is shouldn't it be 4 because there frequency is a restriction? How to  know how many restrictions are there?

Comment: There are six possible values $0,1,2,3,4,5$ for the numbers of heads and $6-1=5$

Comment: frequency is one type of restriction can you tell any others ??